# Testing Google sign-in Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, google-signin, ui-testing

I'm a student in Computer science. For my software engineering project, I need to implement an Android login with Google.
The login implementation works fine, but I need to test the interface. I use Espresso for testing. The problem is, I really don't know how to do this.
Can someone help me please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Espresso recorder](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder), which can be found in the Android Studios:

[image]

After this, it will open your application and you can do your E2E (End-to-End) test to your application. After you are ready, you just save the recorder-output and you can try to run your test. Also good video here about Espresso Recorder [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRkDVvB106k).

Beware with the passwords while uploading things to any [Version Control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).